# Valid javascript object property names

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work out what is considered valid for the property name of a javascript object.  For example

```
var b = {}
b['-^colour'] = "blue";     // Works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari
b['colour'] = "green";      // Ditto
alert(b['-^colour']);       // Ditto
alert(b.colour);            // Ditto
for(prop in b) alert(prop); // Ditto
//alert(b.-^colour);     // Fails (expected)
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names) details valid javascript variable names, and '-^colour' is clearly not valid (as a variable name). Does the same apply to object property names? Looking at the above I'm trying to work out if

1. b['-^colour'] is invalid, but works in all browsers by quirk, and I shouldn't trust it to work going forward
2. b['-^colour'] is completely valid, but it's just of a form that can only be accessed in this manner - (it's supported so Objects can be used as maps perhaps?)
3. Something else

As an aside, a global variable in javascript might be declared at the top level as

```
var abc = 0;
```

but could also be created (as I understand it) with

```
window['abc'] = 0;
```

the following works in all the above browsers

```
window['@£$%'] = "bling!";
alert(window['@£$%']);
```

Is this valid? It seems to contradict the variable naming rules - or am I not declaring a variable there?  What's the difference between a variable and an object property name?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, objects can be used as maps, and any string can be a property name.  As you've discovered, some properties can *only* be accessed using the bracket syntax.

```
window['abc']
```

is accessing a property.  It is not a variable, even though it refers to the same value (at the global level) as:

```
abc
```

Comment: "An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation." ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties))

Comment: ***Márton raises a very important point.*** While at first it may appear as though any JS object can take anything as a valid object key, it isn't quite the case -- Márton correctly points out that such property keys are actually converted to strings. Consider `var x=new function X(){};`, `var y=new function Y(){};`, and `obj={x:true};` -- `obj[y]` will output `true`, because both `x` and `y`, when used as an object key, are both converted to the same string `"[object Object]"`

Comment: To be clear, given my previous comment's example, `obj[x] === obj[y] === obj["[object Object]"]`

Comment: I'll point out that the reason for restrictions on identifier names (even though JS could presumably handle any string internally as a variable or property identifier) is primarily to avoid  syntactical ambiguity.    Consider a property name with a dash:  `x=obj.my-prop`.  It would be unclear (both to the reader and the parser) if that's a property named "my-prop" or if the intent was to subtract  a variable "prop" from  "obj.my".   `x=obj["my-prop"]` makes it clear the name is a string.

Answer (score 15):

Object property naming rules and variable naming rules are separate. The standard only "reserves" a handful of property names (such as `prototype` and `constructor`, IIRC), but other than those, any string goes.

Except when the execution environment (i.e. the browser) decides to add more magic properties, of course. (I hear setting `__proto__` breaks some things in quite weird ways)

Comment: Thanks Matti - tough to work out who to give the answer, both answered, but with different (useful) information - went with first answer.  Cheers.

Comment: when you set `__proto__` to null, what does that break except for the prototype chain (so it's a faster property lookup), if you need it as a simple hash table for value pairs?

Answer (score 9):

1. Every time you create a global variable you create in fact a new member of a **global object** (which is `window` in browser environment, `global` in Node.js, etc.). This is why `window.x` is exactly the same like (global) `var x`, `this.x` or just `x`.
2. Understanding JavaScript **object like a map** is quite right, because: a) you can add a new element dynamically - at any moment; b) the element can have any name - also including special characters, c) you can try to access a non-existing element of an object/map and it is not an error, d) you can remove an element from an object.
3. If you like to access object members with standard **dot notation** (eg. `a.x`) you are not allowed to use any special characters different than _ or $; also the name cannot start from a number. For all other cases you are forced to use square brackets and quotation marks to access object elements.