# get MongoDB ObjectId in JSON via Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

This is my JSON from PHP:

```
{"data" :
    [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "$id" : "4f977259b1445dce24000000"
            },
            "headline" : "asdfasdf",
            "date" : {
                "sec" : 1333584000,
                "usec" : 0
            },
            "text":"asdfasdfas"
        }
    ]
}
```

In Javascript I want to use the values and it works fine with

```
obj = JSON.parse(request);
console.log(obj.data[i].headline);
```

But how do I get the ObjectId?

It does not work like this:

```
console.log(obj.data[i]._id.$id);
```

Comment: I can verify that the answers gillesc and reach4thelasers work (at least in Safari). You may also want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work as expected when I try it http://jsfiddle.net/2CSWr/

```
console.log(json.data[0]._id.$id);​
```

does output the right value

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
console.log(obj.data[0]._id['$id']);
```