# Using property names that start with an underscore ("_")

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this in my Node script (simplified for this question):

```
var http = require("http"),
    url = require("url"),
    options = url.parse("http://example.com/"),
    moreOptions = url.parse("http://example.net/"),
    callback,
    request,
    moreDifferentRequest;

callback = function( res ) {
    console.log(res.socket._httpMessage._headers.host);
}

request = http.request( options, callback );
request.end();

moreDifferentRequest = http.request( moreDifferentOptions, callback );
moreDifferentRequest.end();
```

I'm grabbing the hostname from `res.socket._httpMessage._headers.host` because it does not exist in `res.headers`.

But the underscores give me pause. They say to me, "Hey, this is to be treated like a private property for internal use only by `socket`, so don't read it, because it might totally get changed around in a later version and we're not going to tell you."

If I am right to think that I'm *Doing It Wrong* here, what is the correct way to get the hostname inside the callback? Or am I just totally misinterpreting the underscores and what I'm doing is fine?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they are trying to say. The right way would be of course to use public, documented APIs if that's possible. But if it's not possible, then you must do this and realize it's on you if something breaks.

Comment: Take a look to **@David de Rosier third point** here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217209/1601332 // maybe give you some light about it ;-)   Good Luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what they are trying to say. 
The right way would of course be public, documented APIs if that's possible. But if it's not possible, then you must do this and realize it's on you if something breaks.

---

Since you are sending the request, you can get the host header from:

```
options.host
```

HTTP responses don't have a host header, it's the client (you) that sends the host header in a request.

---

With wrapper function:

```
var http = require("http"),
    opts = require("url").parse( "http://stackoverflow.com" );


function wrapper( options, callback ) {
    return function() {
        args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        args.push( options );
        return callback.apply( this, args );
    }
}

request = http.request( opts, wrapper(opts, function(response, options){
    console.log( options.host );
}));

request.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Since I'm using the same callback for the two simultaneous requests using `options` and `moreDifferentOptions`, I can't just look at `options`. Inside the callback, the host does show up as a property key (not value) inside `this.agent.sockets` so that might be usable, although that doesn't quite pass the smell test either. Better than using things I'm explicitly warned off of, though, I imagine. (I see now I typo'ed in my question and didn't use the right options for the second call. Fixed.)

Comment: @Trott I edited in a wrapper function. Though there are many other possible solutions. Since you are the giver of the host header there should not be much hoop jumping to get it back. :P

Comment: Ah yes, I feel silly not being able to figure that out. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!