# Json data contains date and time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, time

I have the following JSON Data:

```
{
    "city": {
        "city_code":"DE0001516",
        "post":"28195",
        "forecast": {
            "2012-09-10": {
                "p":"24",
                "w":"10",
                "06:00": {
                    "p":"5",
                    "w":"20",
                    "tn":"15",
                    "tx":"21",
                    "w_txt":"wolkig"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I read the data through this function:

```
function(data){ $("#").html(data.city.post); }
```

How do I get the data from 06:00?

```
function(data){ $("#").html( data.city.forecast.2012-09-10.06:00.w); }
```

doesn’t work. I think this has something to do with time and date format.

Comment: It has to do with how you notate keys on JavaScript objects. Try this: `data.city.forecast["2012-09-10"]["06:00"].w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read property names with those special characters in them. They need to be quoted:

```
data.city.forecast["2012-09-10"]["06:00"].w
```

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names):

> any string can be a property name ... some
>   properties can only be accessed using the bracket syntax.

Comment: Thank you! Every day will change the json file and the date will be overwritten with a current date. How should I query? If I write in my javascript for exemple 2012-09-10, my javascript will not be able to read the data on the next day.

Comment: @DariaDuda make them dynamic e.g. `var date = "2012-09-10"; data.city.forecast[date];`

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
data.city.forecast['2012-09-10']['06:00'].w
```

---

Another problem is `$("#")`. The selector seems to be wrong. Which element are you targeting ?

Comment: I load the data on my main.html page (<div id=aa>). Correctly would be $ ("#aa").

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation:

```
data.city.forecast['2012-09-10']['06:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data.city.forecast["2012-09-10"]["06:00"].w
```