# Javascript: Can a string containing a newline "\n" be used as a property name?

Tags: javascript

It is clear why I would not want to do this. But I have little choice in the matter.

Will browsers be able to handle this?

Chrome seems to be okay with it:

```
> var x = {};
> x['a\nb'] = 1;
1
> x
Object
a b: 1
__proto__: Object
> Object.keys(x)
["a
b"]
```

Comment: I guess it's okay, except the consoles might have a hard time displaying that.

Comment: Any valid string literal can be used as a property name (even an empty string, e.g. `x[''] = 1;`).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Browsers should be able to handle that. You'll just have to use bracket notation to access that property.