# How to create a javascript object that has a space?

Tags: javascript

I have a javscript object that I want to look like the following:

```
myObject = {the key:["value","value2","value3"]}
```

If I remove the space from the object such that it looks like this:

```
myObject = {thekey:["value","value2","value3"]}
```

there is no issue. How can I create an object with the above formatting?

Comment: Can you explain what/how it didn't work when quoting they key?  That works just fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/66v6ocvz/

Comment: @j08691 From the question " I tried using quotes around "the key" but that didn't work."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid javascript object property names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names)

Comment: Yes my fault. I messed something up as I was writing it. Vote to close if you like

Answer (score 1):

You can use quotes:

```
myObject = {'the key':["value","value2","value3"]}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v5ekbzgf/)

Comment: The question claims that this was already tried and did not work (though of course it does)

Comment: Yes my fault. I messed something up as I was writing it. Vote to close if you like

Comment: @JamesMontagne : that is why I've provided the exact working example instead of just  posting *use quotes*.

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes for keys:

```
myObject = {"the key":["value","value2","value3"]}
```