# How safe is to assume, when creating an object, that non-string keys will be converted to strings using toString()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, computed-properties

As part of a library I write, I want to let the user to pass functions as object's keys:

https://github.com/welldone-software/redux-toolbelt/tree/master/packages/redux-toolbelt#makereducer

For example, in the following, `increaseBy` is a function with a custom `toString()` that returns a string and `decreaseBy.TYPE` is a string.

```
const reducer = makeReducer({
  [increaseBy]: (state, {payload}) => state + payload,
  [decreaseBy.TYPE]: (state, {payload}) => state - payload,
}, { defaultState: 100 })
```

Where `increaseBy` is a function that has a custom `toString()` that resolves to a string.

[JS translates any key to string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) using `toString()` so it works, but my question is:

**how safe is it?**

Comment: Technically, it is safe in an ES2015 environment. However, you now rely on implicit type coercion. Everyone looking at your code can't immediately tell what property names the object has. And consider functions without a custom `toString`: `const id = x => x; o = {[id]: "foo"}`
yields `{x => x: "foo"}`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. If you look at our library it is clear from the flow. I don't just assign a random function with custom `toString()` on it as object's key :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ES6 specification, under section ["12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) for *"ComputedPropertyName"* in the fourth step we have:

> 4. Return ToPropertyKey(propName).

which under ["7.1.14 ToPropertyKey ( argument )"](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-topropertykey) in the fourth step:

> 4. Return ToString(key).

So the result of `[expression]` will become `toString`. On the other hand [*any* string is a valid key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2940427/1841194) for a property, though some of them can only be accessed via brackets.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: But I didn't understand your comment with accessing via brackets. what it has to do with what I asked?

Comment: @VitalikZaidman It has nothing to do with what you've asked. I only wanted to note that not all properties can be accessed by dot notation, some of them only can be accessed using square brackets.