# Invalid template when constructing Dynamic Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am constructing a dynamic Kendo UI grid with dynamic columns. It fails to render the data to the grid.

I am using ASP.NET Core webAPI which returns dynamic columns and its data.

I followed [this article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/create-with-dynamic-columns-and-data-types).

On my API call success event, I do the following logic:

```
onSuccess: function (readings) {
    console.log(readings);
    var myCoulmns = [];
    var myFields = {}; // I am not using this
    var model = generateModel(readings[0]);
    readings.forEach(function (obj) {
        for (key in obj) {
            console.log(key + ': ' + obj[key]);
            if (key === "Id") {
                myCoulmns.push({
                    field: key,
                    title: key,
                    width: 240,
                    hidden: true
                });
                myFields["Id"] = { type: "number" };
            }
            else if (key === "RadioChannel") {
                myCoulmns.push( {
                    field: "RadioChannel",
                    title: "Radio Channel",
                    width: 240
                });
                myFields["RadioChannel"]= { type: "string" };
            }
            else if (key === "Units") {
                myCoulmns.push( {
                    field: "Units",
                    title: "Units",
                    width: 150
                });
                myFields["Units"] = { type: "string" };
            } else {
                myCoulmns.push( {
                    field: key,
                    title: getFormatedDate(key),
                    width: 200
                    //format: "{0:n}"
                });
                myFields[key] = { type: "number" };
            }
        }
    });

    $("#monitorReadingGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            schema: {
                model: model
            },
            data: readings,
            pageSize: 20
        },
        columns: myCoulmns,
        height: 550,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: false,
        filterable: false,
        //columMenu:true,
        pageable: {
            input: true,
            numeric: false
        }
    });
    //$("#montior-data").show();
}
```

Other functions

```
var isDateField = [];
function getFormatedDate(key) {
    var day = key.substr(0, 2);
    var month = key.substr(2, 3);
    var year = key.substr(5, 4);
    var hour = key.substr(9, 2);
    var minute = key.substr(11, 2);
    var tt = key.substr(13, 2);
    return month + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + tt;
}

function generateModel(dataItem) {
    var model = {};
    var fields = {};
    for (var property in dataItem) {
        if (property.indexOf("Id") !== -1) {
            model["id"] = property;
        }
        var propType = typeof dataItem[property];

        if (propType === "number") {
            fields[property] = {
                type: "number",
                validation: {
                    required: true
                }
            };
            if (model.id === property) {
                fields[property].editable = false;
                fields[property].validation.required = false;
            }
        } else if (propType === "boolean") {
            fields[property] = {
                type: "boolean"
            };
        } else if (propType === "string") {
            var parsedDate = kendo.parseDate(dataItem[property]);
            if (parsedDate) {
                fields[property] = {
                    type: "date",
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                };
                isDateField[property] = true;
            } else {
                fields[property] = {
                    type: "string",
                    validation: {
                        required: true
                    }
                };
            }
        } else {
            fields[property] = {
                validation: {
                    required: true
                }
            };
        }
    }

    model.fields = fields;

    return model;
}
```

Here's the data that is returned from the webAPI:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1000,
      "RadioChannel":"0D_A1",
      "Units":"Gs",
      "22May20190522PM":-367.25849333773,
      "22May20190521PM":-367.25849333773,
      "22May20190520PM":-368.24099331991,
      "22May20190519PM":-367.84799332704,
      "22May20190513PM":0.0,
      "22May20190509PM":-367.84799332704,
      "22May20190502PM":-367.45499333417,
      "22May20190501PM":-367.25849333773,
      "22May20190500PM":-366.37424335377,
      "22May20190459PM":-367.94624332526
   },
   {  
      "Id":1010,
      "RadioChannel":"0D_S1",
      "Units":"uStrain",
      "22May20190522PM":-236.57619777032,
      "22May20190521PM":-235.62476990612,
      "22May20190520PM":-235.66136328552,
      "22May20190519PM":-239.68663501865,
      "22May20190513PM":0.0,
      "22May20190509PM":-239.39388798352,
      "22May20190502PM":-237.56421901391,
      "22May20190501PM":-239.0279541896,
      "22May20190500PM":-237.27147197877,
      "22May20190459PM":-237.63740577269
   },
   {  
      "Id":1020,
      "RadioChannel":"Channel 0_Monitoring Temperature",
      "Units":"Degree Farenheit",
      "22May20190522PM":81.0,
      "22May20190521PM":81.0,
      "22May20190520PM":81.0,
      "22May20190519PM":81.0,
      "22May20190509PM":80.0,
      "22May20190502PM":81.0,
      "22May20190501PM":81.0,
      "22May20190500PM":81.0,
      "22May20190459PM":81.0
   },
   {  
      "Id":1030,
      "RadioChannel":"Channel 1_Monitoring Temperature",
      "Units":"Degree Farenheit",
      "22May20190522PM":81.0,
      "22May20190521PM":81.0,
      "22May20190520PM":81.0,
      "22May20190519PM":81.0,
      "22May20190509PM":80.0,
      "22May20190502PM":81.0,
      "22May20190501PM":81.0,
      "22May20190500PM":81.0,
      "22May20190459PM":81.0
   },
   {  
      "Id":1040,
      "RadioChannel":"AFE 0_Model and SN",
      "Units":"General",
      "22May20190522PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190521PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190520PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190519PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190509PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190502PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190501PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190500PM":16777219.0,
      "22May20190459PM":16777219.0
   },
   {  
      "Id":1050,
      "RadioChannel":"Ambient Temp",
      "Units":"Degree Farenheit",
      "22May20190522PM":79.0,
      "22May20190521PM":79.0,
      "22May20190520PM":79.0,
      "22May20190519PM":79.0,
      "22May20190513PM":0.0,
      "22May20190509PM":79.0,
      "22May20190502PM":79.0,
      "22May20190501PM":79.0,
      "22May20190500PM":79.0,
      "22May20190459PM":79.0
   },
   {  
      "Id":1060,
      "RadioChannel":"Core Temp",
      "Units":"Degree Farenheit",
      "22May20190522PM":79.0,
      "22May20190521PM":79.0,
      "22May20190520PM":79.0,
      "22May20190519PM":79.0,
      "22May20190513PM":0.0,
      "22May20190509PM":79.0,
      "22May20190502PM":79.0,
      "22May20190501PM":79.0,
      "22May20190500PM":79.0,
      "22May20190459PM":79.0
   }
]
```

I get this error:

```
VM48006:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Function (<anonymous>)
    at getter (kendo.all.js:2067)
    at Object.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:6082)
    at each (jquery.js:360)
    at new init (kendo.all.js:6068)
    at new init (kendo.all.js:6384)
    at Function.re.create (kendo.all.js:7990)
    at init._dataSource (kendo.all.js:60997)
    at new init (kendo.all.js:57304)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (kendo.all.js:2449)
```

If I change data source (commend schema) then I get invalid template error, but I am not using any templates in the grid.

```
dataSource: {
    //schema: {
    //    model: model
    //},
    data: readings,
    pageSize: 20
},
```

Comment: As described by @HaBo in his answer, your object property names are not valid for Kendo UI.  Internally, the grid is using dot syntax to access the properties of your data object.  Properties starting with numbers accessed by dot syntax is invalid.  See [Valid javascript object property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your JSON data property names
 `[{"Id":1000,"RadioChannel":"0D_A1","Units":"Gs","22May20190522PM":-367.25849333773,"22May20190521PM":-367.25849333773,"22May20190520PM":-368.24099331991,"22May20190519PM":-367.84799332704,"22May20190513PM":0.0,"22May20190509PM":-367.84799332704,"22May20190502PM":-367.45499333417,"22May20190501PM":-367.25849333773,"22May20190500PM":-366.37424335377,"22May20190459PM":-367.94624332526}]`

if you change your property names to start with string instead of digits, then all your code works.

```
22May20190520PM => May2220190520PM
```

Comment: Also, I'd suggest removing no alphabetic characters like hyphens and such.